# How to pass data on button clicked in cell to another add to cart page tableview?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, replace, shopping-cart

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WzYPA.jpg)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/USokO.png)

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import PanModal

var sum = ""

class CustomBottomSheet: UITableViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var cartTitle: UILabel!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var titleLBbottom: UILabel!
    //가격
    @IBOutlet weak var priceLBbottom: UILabel!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var wonLB: UILabel!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var totalLB: UILabel!
    // 입력갯수
    @IBOutlet weak var countLB: UILabel!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var gaeLB: UILabel!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var addtoCartPage: UIButton!
    
    
    @IBOutlet weak var stepper: UIStepper!
    
    //⭐️ let sum
    @IBAction func stepperValueChanged(_ sender: UIStepper) {
        
        let price = MenuData.MenuDATAS[index].price
        let sum = Int(sender.value) * price
        
        countLB.text = Int(sender.value).description
        priceLBbottom.text = String(sum)
        
    }
    
    var index: Int = 0
    
    var collectMemuData: [MenuData] = []
    
    var quantity: Int = 0
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        collectMemuData = MenuData.MenuDATAS
        
        stepperSetup()
        updatePriceLabel()
        
    }
    
    func bottomsetup(with menuData: MenuData){
        titleLBbottom.text = menuData.title
        priceLBbottom.text = String(menuData.price)
        
        
    }
    
    func stepperSetup() {
        stepper.wraps = true
        stepper.autorepeat = true
        stepper.minimumValue = 0
        stepper.maximumValue = 15
        stepper.value = 0
    }
    
    @IBAction func addtoCartPageSELELTED(_ sender: UIButton) {
        print("버튼이 눌림")
    }
     
}

extension CustomBottomSheet: PanModalPresentable {
    var panScrollable: UIScrollView? {
        return tableView
    }
    
    var shortFormHeight: PanModalHeight {
        return .contentHeight(200)
    }
    
    var longFormHeight: PanModalHeight {
        return .maxHeightWithTopInset(40)
        
    }
    
    func calculatePrice(for quantity: Int) -> Double {
        let basePrice = 10.0
        let pricePerItem = 2.0
        return basePrice + (Double(quantity) * pricePerItem)
        
    }
    
    func updatePriceLabel() {
        let price = calculatePrice(for: quantity)
        priceLBbottom.text = String(format: "A", price)
    }
    
}
```

```
import UIKit

class ADDTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var addTitleLB: UILabel!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var totalcountLB: UILabel!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var totalPriceLB: UILabel!
    
}
```

```
import UIKit

class AddviewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var addTableView: UITableView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        addTableView.dataSource = self
        
    }
    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        addTableView.reloadData()
    }
    
}

extension AddviewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 0
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ADDTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! ADDTableViewCell
        
        return cell
    }
}
```

import UIKit

I want to know the pass data on "add to cart"button(in CustomBottomSheet) clicked in cell to another add to cart page tableview(addTableView,ADDTableViewCell)

I have a terrible headache because of this problem.
please help me..

the button(in CustomBottomSheet) -> (addTableView,ADDTableViewCell)

Comment: Are you trying to present `CustomBottomSheet` as a Modal View/BottomSeet controller on top of `AddviewController`? And once you have filled out the necessary information, do you want to dismiss `CustomBottomSheet` and append the data to the `AddviewController` tableView?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the tableView(_:didSelectRowAt:) method? This allows you to pass the selected data in a cell to another view controller.